# How to create an outlet in XCode 5

Tags: xcode5

I'm new to iOS development and am working through some tutorials. I'm using XCode 5 but the tutorials are a re for XCode 4, and I'm having problems creating outlets.

I have a `UIViewController` containing two buttons. I click on the Assistant Editor icon to view the `.h` file next to the design surface. Then I ctrl-drag one of the buttons onto the `.h` file. A popup appears and the tutorial says that I should be able to select the connection as either `Outlet` or `Action`, but the connection chooser is greyed-out and I can only create an `Action`.

So, how do I create an `Outlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I was trying to ctrl-drag into the .m file, not the .h file. When I selected the .h file I was able to create the outlet. Newbie error!

Answer (score 1):

That should work.  If the File Owner of the .xib file the same as the .h file you are control-dragging to, then it should automatically be an Outlet in the popup.